# Delay with CollectionView Did Select

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I'm getting a second long delay when selecting my collectionview cell. Here is my current code for collection view did select:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = PopUpCellViewController(nibName: "PopUpCellViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    print("called")
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AnnotatedPhotoCell
    sourceCell = cell
    vc.picture = resizeImage(image: cell.imageView.image!, targetSize: CGSize(width: (view.bounds.width - 45),height: 0))
    vc.comment = cell.commentLabel
    var image = UIImage(named: "back_button_thick")
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = image
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}

func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize

    newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

I am using a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning. I am confident that there is no delay with my UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning. There seems to be an issue with my CollectionView Did select function. If switch my code in my didSelect function for a print statement, there is no longera delay.

Comment: Are you using some IBInspectable in next VC or loading some bulky data in ViewDidLoad of next VC. If you are providing IBInspecatble of UIView to some other element than the view will load with complaining unsatisfiable constraints. And for choosing proper one it will take some seconds.

Comment: move this line `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` at the end of your method `didSelectItemAt`. You supposed to set all the members of the  destination object before pushing it

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions:

**1: PROBABLY NOT:** I'm guessing that it's giving an annoying delay because it's taking a while for your app to run the code to get the nib file, and change all those things while it shouldn't.

**2: PROBABLY:** Perhaps running it on a real device will help. Xcode always has bugs, so don't worry. :)